# how to access a tuple element by a non-const variable?

Tags: c++

I have a tuple that I want to access element by a variable, how can I achieve this?
Now I use the switch case to solve this problem. like this:

```
unsigned short& indices(unsigned char samecnt) {
        
        switch (samecnt)
        {
        case 12:
            return std::get<12>(view).indices;
        case 11:
            return std::get<11>(view).indices;
        }
}
```

the tuple is view_rep :

```
template<unsigned char N>
struct poker_view
{
    unsigned short  indices = 0;
    constexpr static unsigned char count = N;
};

using wilds_view = poker_view<1>;
template<int N, class... Types>
struct poker_view_rep :public poker_view_rep<N - 1, poker_view<N - 1>, Types...> {

};
template<class... Types>
struct poker_view_rep<1, Types...>
{
    using type = std::tuple<wilds_view, Types...>;
};
using view_rep = poker_view_rep<13>::type;
```

Comment: Please show what `view` is, tuples aren't meant to be indexed since each element can be a different type.

Comment: This is definitely feeling like something went wrong in development. The runtime shouldn't be indexing into tuples; you either don't want a tuple, or your compiler should be doing the indexing with template magic, and I'd almost bet it's the former.

Comment: `using view_rep = std::array<unsigned short, 13>;` seems to replace your `tuple`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot indeed use non-constant expression as template parameter, so you have to "transform" your runtime value into constexpr with some dispatching. `switch` is an alternative.

In your case, you might use array:

```
unsigned short& indices(std::index_sequence<Is...>, unsigned char samecnt) {
    std::array<unsigned short*, sizeof...(Is)> arr{{&std::get<Is>(view).indices...}};
    return *arr[samecnt];
}

unsigned short& indices(std::index_sequence<Is...>, unsigned char samecnt) {
    return indices(std::make_index_sequence<13>(), samecnt);
}
```

or with `std::apply`:

```
unsigned short& indices(std::index_sequence<Is...>, unsigned char samecnt) {
    return std::apply([](auto&... args) -> unsigned short&
               { return std::array{{&args.indices...}}[samecnt]; }, view);
}
```